# Как сделать запись в файл с интервалом в каждых 100 миллисекунд от системного времени?

Tags: java, файлы

Как можно ораганизовать запись в файл с фиксированным интервалом - каждые 100 миллисекунд?

Comment: что значит от системного времени?

Comment: текущее время ,которое отображается в ОС

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае для повторяющихся задач используйте [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) (и забудьте про бесконечные циклы со `sleep`).

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::doWrite, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// ...

public void doWrite() {
    // ваш код здесь
}
```

Comment: а если нужно писать каждых 100 миллисекунд и каждых 2 секунды,как это организовать в одном методе?

Comment: ну вызовите еще раз `executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::doWrite, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: а не нарушится интервал в 100миллисекунд между вызовами в таком случаи?

Comment: будет одна задача, выполняющаяся каждые 100 мс, и другая, задача выполняющаяся каждые 2 с, не связанные друг с другом (и вам придется думать о синхронизации доступа к файлу, если вы будете писать в один и тот же файл)

Answer (score -1):

`WriteToFile()` - это должна быть ваша функция

```
for(;;) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    writeToFile()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще есть несколько вариантов решения. Самый просто, на мой взгляд, это использование `java.util.Timer`:

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeToFile();
        }
    }, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(100));
```

Comment: Причем тут `Timer`, когда используете `Sheduler`. непонятно.

Comment: @And а что вас смущает в ответе? код делает именно то, что требовалось - запускать задачу через каждые 100 милисекунды

Comment: То, что таймер тут не причем и делает это шедулер, прочитайте ещe разок, шедулер, а не таймер

Comment: @And почитайте доки к методу и к классу хотя бы один раз, чтобы вас не смущало присутствие слова `Timer` отсутствие `Sheduler` в названии класса