# Как сделать, чтобы поток повторялся каждые 15 секунд?

Tags: android, android-threads

Нужно, чтобы поток запускался сново через каждые 15 секунд. Внутри потока происходит обращение к серверу.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 270; i++) {
                        final Response response =  requestInterface.getCard().execute();
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                items.add((Card)response.body());
                                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Comment: Обычно такие задачи вот так решаются: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567028/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85-100-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80/567033#567033

Comment: Похоже на то, что вам может подойти Service. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru
Их используют для таких задач, как цикличное обращение к серверу в фоне.